# Is there a way for cascade select in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, cascade

I am facing a scenario in which I have a foreign reference field of the same table and I need to get the list of values of such foreign references. For eg:

```
Field1 | Field2
----------------
X      |   Y
Y      |   Z
Z      |   A
```

Now I want to cascade select Field2 as in I want the output to be {Y,Z,A}.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think SQL recursive queries is what you're searching for. Its syntax looks like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE <cte_name> (column, ...) AS (
<non-recursive_term>
UNION ALL
<recursive_term>)
SELECT ... FROM <cte_name>;
```

In your case it will look like this:

1. Create table and populate it:

   ```
   create table example (field1 char(1), field2 char(1));
   insert into example values ('X', 'Y');
   insert into example values ('Y', 'Z');
   insert into example values ('Z', 'A');
   select * from example;
   ```

   Result:

   ```
    field1 | field2 
    -------+--------
     X     | Y
     Y     | Z
     Z     | A
    (3 rows)
   ```
2. Query:

   ```
    WITH RECURSIVE linked_example(list, first, last) AS (
      SELECT field1 || ', ' || field2, field1, field2 FROM example
      UNION ALL
      SELECT list || ', ' || field2, first, field2
        FROM
          linked_example, example
        WHERE
          last = field1
    )
    SELECT * from linked_example;
   ```

   Result:

   ```
        list    | first | last 
    ------------+-------+------
     X, Y       | X     | Y
     Y, Z       | Y     | Z
     Z, A       | Z     | A
     X, Y, Z    | X     | Z
     Y, Z, A    | Y     | A
     X, Y, Z, A | X     | A
    (6 rows)
   ```
3. Now, just limit the query with WHERE clause:

   ```
    WITH RECURSIVE linked_example(list, first, last) AS (
      SELECT field1 || ', ' || field2, field1, field2 FROM example
      UNION ALL
      SELECT list || ', ' || field2, first, field2
        FROM
          linked_example, example
        WHERE
          last = field1
    )
    SELECT * from linked_example WHERE first = 'Y';
   ```

   Result:

   ```
      list   | first | last 
    ---------+-------+------
     Y, Z    | Y     | Z
     Y, Z, A | Y     | A
    (2 rows)
   ```

   As you can see, the last row is exactly what you want.

If you want more information and examples regarding SQL recursive queries, you can read my two articles covering this topic:

- [Get to know the power of SQL recursive queries](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/sql-recursive-queries)
- [Do It In SQL: Recursive Tree Traversal](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/do-it-in-sql-recursive-tree-traversal)

Comment: Hi Michal, I just wanted to know if the performance is something that I need to be concerned about?

Comment: Well, performance is something you should ALWAYS think about. You can do some optimizations: reorganize the query to select only what is really necessary, properly index your table, etc. If you still have problems with performance, consider using recursive materialized views - it's available since PostgreSQL 9.3: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createview.html

Comment: To be precise: I'm **almost sure** it supports materialized recursive views, but not 100% sure. I'd need to check this. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: No issues .. Thanks for the guidance. :)

Comment: @MichałKołodziejski: you could use a recursive query for a materialized view in 9.2 as well. Just with a slightly different syntax.

Comment: The very best guide about recursive. Thanks a lot, you saved my day :)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this simply using a jonction:

```
select a.field1, a.field2, b.field2
from my_table a
inner join my_table b
on a.field2 =b.field1
```

[SQL FIddle sample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/991b8/1)

Comment: Err.... can it be done for a particular X i.e, if I pass x then I require Y,Z,A something like fetching parents of field. I think recursive query is an answer but it can be of performance concerns if the level is as deep as 50.